# Kubernetes Scheduling Framework, "kubernetes-sigs/scheduler-plugins" [Error] for "./hack/update-codegen.sh"

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a new plugin for "kubernetes-sigs/scheduler-plugins" using links

1. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/scheduler-plugins/blob/master/doc/develop.md
2. https://github.com/wangchen615/scheduler-plugins/tree/kubecon22/pkg/scorebylabel

But getting following Warnings for command `./hack/update-codegen.sh`

Warnings:

```
Generating deepcopy funcs
Generating defaulters
Generating conversions
WARNING: generate-groups.sh is deprecated.
WARNING: Please use k8s.io/code-generator/kube_codegen.sh instead.

WARNING: Specifying "all" as a generator is deprecated.
WARNING: Please list the specific generators needed.
WARNING: "all" is now an alias for "applyconfiguration,client,deepcopy,informer,lister"; new code generators WILL NOT be added to this set

WARNING: generate-internal-groups.sh is deprecated.
WARNING: Please use k8s.io/code-generator/kube_codegen.sh instead.

Generating deepcopy funcs
Generating apply configuration for scheduling:v1alpha1 at sigs.k8s.io/scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/applyconfiguration
Generating clientset for scheduling:v1alpha1 at sigs.k8s.io/scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/clientset
Generating listers for scheduling:v1alpha1 at sigs.k8s.io/scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/listers
Generating informers for scheduling:v1alpha1 at sigs.k8s.io/scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/informers

How to solve this?


I have added the plugin "ScoreByLabel" by referring https://github.com/wangchen615/scheduler-plugins/tree/kubecon22/pkg/scorebylabel and executed command "./hack/update-codegen.sh"

Expectation was to update the generated files with functions as DeepCopy for the added structures.
```

Comment: For the error, can you check to see if `/usr/src/sigs.k8s.io/scheduler-plugins/vendor/k8s.io/code-generator/generate-internal-groups.sh` has the executable bit set?

Comment: Thanks. As per your suggestion, I have executed command chmod u+x generate-internal-groups.sh 
AND run the command ./hack/update-codegen.sh again
Vendor permission error gone with same warnings
WARNING: generate-internal-groups.sh is deprecated. ........
Generating apply configuration for scheduling:v1alpha1 at sigs.k8s.io/scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/applyconfiguration
Generating clientset for ....../scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/clientset
Generating listers for ...../scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/listers
Generating informers for ....scheduler-plugins/pkg/generated/informers